# regex to search for a string that matches almost anything except a |

Tags: regex

I would like to match the following:

cat followed by any characters except `|`

For example, cat etc | reboot should not match, because of the '|'

I know that this

```
cat.*[^\|]
```

does not work when I try it.

Comment: Why do you need a regex solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't abuse regexps for trivial tasks that can be accomplished faster and easier differently. For example in PHP:

```
$str = trim($input);
if(strpos($str, '|') === FALSE && strpos($str, 'cat') === 0)
  die('Match found!');
```

This will outperform the regexp solution by far.

Having said that, the [proper answer is `/^cat[^|\n]+$/gm`](http://regexr.com/39f7d).